# In the Artemis Fowl film, why is Mulch in MI6, rather than Irish, custody?

Tags: movie, artemis-fowl

The first title card in the Artemis Fowl film informs the audience that we are seeing Fowl Manor in Ireland, and then, just to make clear that this is not Northern Ireland, shows Mulch Diggums being arrested by the Gardaí.

Yet, just we see him being arrested by Irish police, Mulch is shown in custody of the British foreign intelligence service, MI6.  Why and how would the Irish authorities turn him over to the British so quickly and secret? He was arrested by ordinary gardaí, so it seems bizarre there would be a seemingly immediate extraordinary rendition to a shadowy intelligence service of another country, rather than just interrogating the prisoner using Ireland's own élite units.

Comment: While the writers may indeed have had no idea, MI-6 *is* an *exterior* intelligence agency.

Answer (score 3):

Out of universe, this seems like a possible writers' error, even though the lead writer on  the film was Irish. Alternately, it may have been done to keep the film relatable for international audiences that are familiar with MI6 and not G-2.

That said, it would not be so implausible in the real world. MI6 is an exterior intelligence agency that primarily works to identify foreign threats. They have agents all over the world, [including in Ireland.](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.thejournal.ie/mi6-spies-ireland-3552898-Aug2017/%3famp=1) It seems plausible that they might attempt to get a high-value target from the Irish police. As the previous article indicates, the Gardaí almost certainly work with British intelligence:

> “An Garda Síochána liaise closely with our security and law enforcement partners throughout Europe to share and assess any relevant intelligence and its potential impact on this jurisdiction,” the spokesperson said.
>
> The Special Detective Unit (SDU) – an elite arm of the gardaí – has been liaising with its British counterparts and offering its intelligence capabilities to assist the spies with their work here.

In negotiations between allied countries over whose intelligence agencies get to interrogate and have custody of extremely valuable prisoners, I would expect the more powerful country to generally win out. For the same reason, it would not have been surprising if CIA agents from the United States had been given custody instead, as has happened in a few cases. These chains of custody can be quite complicated: for instance, [someone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdelhakim_Belhaj)
might be arrested by Thai authorities on the basis of British intelligence, handed over to an American intelligence agency, and later transferred to Libya for interrogation.

This is particularly the case if the more powerful intelligence agency has a decent excuse. Mulch is thought to have been working with Artemis Fowl to steal the following items:

> Fowl is a known collector
> and antiquities dealer,
> but in dramatic new revelations,
> he is also suspected
> to have been behind
> some of the biggest robberies
> of the past 10 years,
> including the disappearance
> of the **priceless Rosetta Stone
> from the British Museum**,
> the irreplaceable 14th century
> Boru's harp,
> and the iconic Book of Kells
> from Trinity College, Dublin.

Since the Rosetta Stone is rather well-known, MI6 has a good excuse to put pressure on the Gardaí or G-2 to turn Mulch over.

Comment: I was going to say Five Eyes, but [RoI isn't part of that](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53699/why-isnt-the-republic-of-ireland-a-member-of-the-five-eyes-security-alliance).

Comment: More thought went into this answer methinks, than into the script for the movie..